# When making 3D model for building, is it better to split it or combine it?

Tags: 3d, 3d-modeling

As the title say, when making 3d model for building (example: school, office, etc). Used for FPS game so it must have detail and texture must be vary so it won't look like repeating/reused. Is it better to make the whole building as one model with multiple materials and UV map, or split it to sub model such as a wall, pillar, floor, etc. I want to know which is more practical or better for a game. I want to know why is it better, advantage and disadvantage of both, or if there's a better technique I can use.

Comment: Both approaches have there advantages and their drawbacks.

Comment: yes, I want to know which is better or more practical for a big building and why? at least give me the reason why i should choose it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense to break assets into pieces as small possible until the workflow overhead gets too much, or the in-game visual repetition breaks immersion.

For example, if you have a model representing some leaves, you could create various different types of vegetation by placing it in different places with slight scale and hue adjustments:

- This **saves disk space**: you only have to store that model once.
- It can also **reduce repetitive work**: if you think of a better model for those leaves, you can make the change to one model and all your in-game vegetation that uses that model will inherit the changes without further changes.

However, this has the mentioned disadvantages:

- Excessive **repetition can break immersion**; if players begin to notice pieces of the environment are used repeatedly, the world feels more fake.
- At some point, **asset management becomes hard**. For a large game, if level designers have to move a lot of objects around to construct something simple, that'll kill their productivity (unless your tools can handle it e.g. by allowing assets to be grouped and such groups duplicated and distributed).

The right value along this gradient comes down to your game:

Cinematic, environment-centric games like [*L.A. Noire*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L.A._Noire) or [*The Wolf Among Us*](https://www.telltalegames.com/thewolfamongus/) have to be most careful about making their environments unique and interesting (so are likely to use more and more detailed assets, and larger models).

On the other hand, [*The Elder Scrolls: Skyrim*](http://www.elderscrolls.com/skyrim/) or [*DOOM*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doom_(series)) can in some segments of the game get away with extremely heavy asset reuse, because the player's attention is elsewhere.

Some games also heavily utilise [procedural generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_generation), which can help get the required variety out of less and smaller assets with less human effort (e.g. [*Minecraft*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minecraft)), or even *almost no static assets at all* (e.g. the upcoming [*Nowhere*](http://www.duangle.com/nowhere)).

Comment: Another note worth adding here is that smaller pieces give more granularity for LOD, culling, or streaming. If your building is all one object and even 1% of it is visible, you have to render the whole thing and have it all in memory. If it's many pieces, you may be able to LOD or cull pieces that are less visible or even not keep them in memory at all, streaming in on demand as the player approaches a point where they'll be able to see each section. The trade-off there is the complexity of the LOD, culling, and streaming systems vs the budget headroom they provide.